# Allow device usage only in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have an USB device, and I want to connect it to VirtualBox, but I don't want to allow any usage of this device on the host machine - it should only forward the device to the guest. How to do this?

Comment: Have you looked through all the settings in VirtualBox? Have you asked the almighty Google for help? Is there anything else that you might have tired that would be useful to help you?

Comment: @Cfinley I've tried to google this, but can't find related solututions. I think question is related to host settings, not VirtualBox.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with VirtualBox, but I know Windows does not have a setting like this. If Windows is unable to use a flash drive, VirtualBox wouldn't be able to use it either. If this is possible, it would be somewhere in VirtualBox.